# Solution for a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

If $x^n$ is a solution for the equation: $y''y'y=48x^9$, what is the value of $n$?

I have the choices: 2,  1,  3,  4,  or 6.

I dont know how to resolve $y''y'y=0$, but maybe i dont need to do it.

And considering the particular solution by guess for $48x^9$ i would take a polynomial order 9: $Ax^9+Bx^8+Cx^7+...+Ix+J$ but even if this is right, there must be another way to answer the question.

Comment: Just differentiate $x^n$ twice and multiply results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y=x^n$ then $y'=nx^{n-1}$ and $y''=n(n-1)x^{n-2}$ hence
$$y''y'y=n^2(n-1)x^{3(n-1)}=48x^9\iff n-1=3\iff n=4$$

Comment: Thanks, i saw that too late...

Comment: You're welcome.